# Time series split cross validation first fold metric name is not available warning

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, time-series, classification

I'm using time series split cross validation and a keras tuner to make a neural network with tensor flow for binary classification and I keep getting this warning on the first fold:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Early stopping conditioned on metric `val_auc` which is not available. Available metrics are: loss,accuracy,precision_1,recall_1,auc_1,val_loss,val_accuracy,val_precision_1,val_recall_1,val_auc_1
18/18 - 1s - loss: 0.5849 - accuracy: 0.8207 - precision_1: 0.8691 - recall_1: 0.8571 - auc_1: 0.9133 - val_loss: 356.0745 - val_accuracy: 0.5301 - val_precision_1: 0.5301 - val_recall_1: 1.0000 - val_auc_1: 0.5000 - 683ms/epoch - 38ms/step
```

I tried clearing the keras session before and during the loop in order to stop having keras rename the variables each time. but it isn't working properly only the first fold has this warning all others are ok. here's the code for my tuner and for the model:

```
    #create the model builder function
    def build_model(hp):
        #create a sequential model
        model_3 = tf.keras.Sequential()

        #set up the options for hyper param tuning
        hp_activation = hp.Choice("activation", values = ["relu","sigmoid","tanh","swish","elu"])
        hp_learning_rate = hp.Choice("learning_rate", values = [0.0001,0.001,0.01,0.1])
        hp_reg_rate = hp.Choice("reg_rate", values = [0.0001,0.001,0.01,0.1])
        hp_regularizer = hp.Choice("regularizer", values = ["l1","l2","l1_l2"])
        hp_num_layers = hp.Int("num_layers",min_value=2,max_value=12)

        #for each number of layers option
        for i in range(hp_num_layers):
            #check regularizer type and set the variable
            if hp_regularizer == "l1":
                reg = regularizers.l1(hp_reg_rate)
            elif hp_regularizer == "l2":
                reg = regularizers.l2(hp_reg_rate)
            else:
                reg = regularizers.l1_l2(l1=hp_reg_rate, l2=hp_reg_rate)

            #add dense layer with tuning hyper parameters
            model_3.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(
                units = hp.Int(f'layer_{i+1}_units', min_value=32, max_value=512, step=32),
                activation=hp_activation, kernel_regularizer = reg))
        
        #add the output layer
        model_3.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 1,activation = "sigmoid" ))

        #compile the model
        model_3.compile(optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = hp_learning_rate),          loss=BinaryCrossentropy(),metrics=["accuracy",Precision(), Recall(), AUC()])


        return model_3

    objective = kt.Objective("val_auc",direction ="max")
    #create a tuner instance
    tuner = kt.Hyperband(build_model,
                         objective = objective,
                         max_epochs = 20,
                         factor = 3,
                         directory = "dir",
                         project_name="x"
                         )
    #set up early stopping
    stop_early = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="val_auc",patience = 5,mode = "max",verbose=1)
    stop_early_2 = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="val_auc",patience = 15,mode = "max",verbose=1)

    tss = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits = 20)

    #create output list for evaluatin metrics
    train_accuracy_output = []
    cv_accuracy_output = []
    test_accuracy_output = []

    train_auc_output = []
    cv_auc_output = []
    test_auc_output = []

    train_precision_output = []
    cv_precision_output = []
    test_precision_output = []


    train_recall_output = []
    cv_recall_output = []
    test_recall_output = []


    #set the fold counter
    fold = 0

    #split test data in X and y removing any data leakage columns
    X_test = test_df.drop(columns = ["y"], axis =1)

    y_test = test_df["y"]


    #clear the session to maintain metric variable names
    tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

    #set up the cross validation for loop and split train and cv by index
    for train_index, test_index in tss.split(X):
        #clear the session to maintain metric variable names
        tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
        X_train, X_cv = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]
        y_train, y_cv = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[test_index]

        #create scaler and poly instance
        scaler = StandardScaler()
        poly = PolynomialFeatures(2)

        #apply poly fit and transformations
        X_train_poly = poly.fit_transform(X_train)
        X_cv_poly = poly.transform(X_cv)
        X_test_poly = poly.transform(X_test)

    
        #apply scaling and transormations
        X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train_poly)
        X_cv_scaled = scaler.transform(X_cv_poly)
        X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test_poly)


        #fit the tuner to the scaled data of this loop iteration
        tuner.search(X_train_scaled,y_train, epochs= 20, validation_data = (X_cv_scaled,y_cv), callbacks = [stop_early])
    
        #store the best hyper parameters 
        best_hps = tuner.get_best_hyperparameters(num_trials=1)[0]

        #create the best model using the best hyperparameters
        model_3 = tuner.hypermodel.build(best_hps)
    
        #train using the best model and store results in history
        history = model_3.fit(X_train_scaled,y_train,epochs = 30,verbose=2,callbacks = stop_early_2,validation_data=(X_cv_scaled, y_cv))
 
        #printout the results
        print(pd.DataFrame(history.history))

        #predictions
        predictions_train = model_3.predict(X_train_scaled)
        predictions_train_binary = (predictions_train > 0.5).astype(int)
    
        predictions_cv = model_3.predict(X_cv_scaled)
        predictions_cv_binary = (predictions_cv > 0.5).astype(int)
    
        predictions_test = model_3.predict(X_test_scaled)
        predictions_test_binary = (predictions_test > 0.5).astype(int)


        #calculate metrics
        train_accuracy = accuracy_score(y_train,predictions_train_binary)
        cv_accuracy = accuracy_score(y_cv,predictions_cv_binary)
        test_accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test,predictions_test_binary)
    
        train_auc =roc_auc_score(y_train,predictions_train)
        cv_auc = roc_auc_score(y_cv, predictions_cv)
        test_auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, predictions_test)

        precision_train = precision_score(y_train, predictions_train_binary)
        precision_cv = precision_score(y_cv, predictions_cv_binary)
        precision_test = precision_score(y_test, predictions_test_binary)

        recall_train = recall_score(y_train, predictions_train_binary)
        recall_cv = recall_score(y_cv, predictions_cv_binary)
        recall_test = recall_score(y_test, predictions_test_binary)

    
  



        #append metric results to output lists
        train_accuracy_output.append(train_accuracy)
        cv_accuracy_output.append(cv_accuracy)
        test_accuracy_output.append(test_accuracy)

        train_auc_output.append(train_auc)
        cv_auc_output.append(cv_auc)
        test_auc_output.append(test_auc)

        train_recall_output.append(recall_train)
        cv_recall_output.append(recall_cv)
        test_recall_output.append(recall_test)

        train_precision_output.append(precision_train)
        cv_precision_output.append(precision_cv)
        test_precision_output.append(precision_test)


    
        #show progress and update counter
        print(f"Fold {fold} completed")
        fold +=1
OUTPUT:


here's an example from the first fold:

Epoch 1/30
WARNING:tensorflow:Early stopping conditioned on metric `val_auc` which is not available. Available metrics are: loss,accuracy,precision_1,recall_1,auc_1,val_loss,val_accuracy,val_precision_1,val_recall_1,val_auc_1
18/18 - 6s - loss: 5.6457 - accuracy: 0.5906 - precision_1: 0.6825 - recall_1: 0.7088 - auc_1: 0.5598 - val_loss: 6.8626 - val_accuracy: 0.5921 - val_precision_1: 0.7070 - val_recall_1: 0.3936 - val_auc_1: 0.6270 - 6s/epoch - 345ms/step

every other fold looks like this:

Epoch 1/30
34/34 - 7s - loss: 4.7037 - accuracy: 0.5258 - precision: 0.5842 - recall: 0.7090 - auc: 0.4763 - val_loss: 3.5043 - val_accuracy: 0.4925 - val_precision: 0.4688 - val_recall: 0.8354 - val_auc: 0.4908 - 7s/epoch - 220ms/step
```